# How do I get an access token of my own account to be stored/used in my server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm going to be using the [Google Cloud Storage JSON API](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api), and the app will only be using *my* Cloud Storage project, and not the individual users'. How do I get an an access token/api key so I can do requests to my Cloud Storage project without having to worry about expired tokens, etc., from AppEngine?

I see that there's a "Server Key" entry in the Cloud Console, but I'm not sure what it's for.

I'm aware about "activating" my AppEngine project with the Google Cloud project (god that's confusing) to achieve what I want, but unfortunately, my AppEngine project is already "activated" to a different Google Cloud project (which doesn't have Cloud Storage enabled), and the Google Cloud project is already associated with another AppEngine project (wat?).

Also, how would I use this "api key" in my requests via the wrapper library? As all samples online are done via OAuth2 and signing requests with a user's access token. (I don't think the wrapper library even has support for non-OAuth2 requests?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your AppEngine project has a service account associated with it. That account can be granted membership in your second project.

To find the name of your service account, head over to the AppEngine console ( https://appengine.google.com ) and choose your AppEngine project. Down under the Application Settings tab, you'll see a "Service Account Name" that looks like an email address.

Now head over to the cloud console ( https://cloud.google.com/console ) and choose the second project, the one you're using for this Google Cloud Storage stuff. While you're there, make sure you've enabled it for Google Cloud Storage (and the JSON version), and that you've set up billing.

Under "permissions", you'll see a list of email addresses. Click "Add member" and put in the address we found earlier in the AppEngine console. Choose between owner, editor, or viewer, depending on what your AppEngine app is going to do need to do.

Alternately, rather than adding that account to the project itself, you could also grant it permissions for just the buckets or objects it needs to use.

When you invoke the Google Cloud Storage JSON API, you can specify which API key you want to use as a keyword argument on the build() function. You can use either API key.

In order to get ahold of credentials for invoking the JSON API, you'll most likely want to use AppAssertionsCredentials, as shown here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine#ServiceAccounts

```
import httplib2
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials
from apiclient import discovery
...
credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write')
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(memcache))
storage = discovery.build(serviceName='storage', version='v1beta2', http=http, developerKey=your_api_key)
```

Also note that, in addition to the JSON API, there is also an AppEngine-specific Python library for accessing Google Cloud Storage: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/

Comment: Thanks. `developerKey` is the "Server Key" in the console, correct? And since via the service account email, only the AppEngine project can have access to the Cloud Storage (and thus I can't test things out on my localhost)?

Comment: Got it working. Thanks! Can't do anything on localhost, so this will be more annoying than I thought. EDIT: (Yes, the "Server Key" is the `developerKey` a.k.a. api key)

Comment: If you want to run from localhost, you have a couple of options. First, you could use the AppEngine GCS library I mentioned at the end. The downside is that this is a local, fake version of GCS, so your real data won't be there. Your other option is to create a new Google service account, which'll use a private key for its credentials. With that private key file, you can access the real Google Cloud Storage locally the same way you'd access it from AppEngine. See https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts

Comment: Note:  generating developer keys:  https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#keys